# OneNote section name changes

Tags: microsoft-onenote

I am trying to change a section name in OneNote but once I do it just reverts back to the old name. This happens when I rename a section as well as when I try to add a New Section. Once I rename the section, in about 3 seconds the old name reverts back, not allowing me to keep any of the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you created the notebook in a place (like a sharepoint location) where you don't have full access.